# How can i keep track that all api' calls are completed that are call by loop in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-services

i am calling alot of api's based on for loop and how can i keep track that all are successfully completed .

I know to how to keep track but that is working on for only one api'call..

So how can i get over this think that i get to know all api' call are completed successfully.

**Here is the method of api that will be call several time by loop.**

```
 getpages(id) {
    let url = ApiAddress.API_ENDPOINT + '/ads/publish/' + id + '/pages';
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    return this
        .http
        .get(url, {headers: headers})
}
```

And i subscribe it in that loop.How will i get to know all are completed successfully .so i can hide the loading bar

Answer (score 0):

By reading the Angular 2 docs I assume that the http.get method returns a promise.

If you want to wait for all your requests to finish using this function you would want all the promises to finish - this is what Promise.all is for (=

And in code:

```js
getpages(id) {
    let url = ApiAddress.API_ENDPOINT + '/ads/publish/' + id + '/pages';
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    return this
        .http
        .get(url, {headers: headers})
}

const IDS_PROMISES = [1,2,3].map(id=>getPages(id)); // Enter your IDS
Promise.all(IDS_PROMISES).then(()=>{
  // Here you can check the status of each request after they are ALL done.
})
```

Comment: i can only use Obseravables ,So can you give solution with Obseravbles Instead of Promice

Answer (score 0):

You can catch errors on API calls by something like this:

`return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers})
                 .catch( err => return Observable.throw( err ) );`

On the subscribe method you can something like this:

`this.getPages(id).subscribe( response => { console.log("success") },
      ( err ) => { console.log("error") } );`

Comment: i know that but how will i keep track that all the api calls are called by loop is successfull